# Functionality of void operator()()

Tags: c++

I am confused about the functionality of `void operator()()`.

Could you tell me about that, for instance:

```
class background_task
{
public:

    void operator()() const
    {
        do_something();
        do_something_else();
    }
};

background_task f;

std::thread my_thread(f);
```

Here, why we need `operator()()`? What is the meaning of the first and second `()`? Actually, I know the operation of normal operator, but this operator is confusing.

Comment: someone was reading concurrency in action :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first `()` is the name of the operator - it's the operator that is invoked when you use `()` on the object. The second `()` is for the parameters, of which there are none.

Here's an example of how you would use it:

```
background_task task;
task();  // calls background_task::operator()
```

Comment: Are there any implicit calls for operator()() except this explicit call task()?

Comment: @forester2012, no you must always call it explicitly although you can use the much more awkward `task.operator()()` syntax as well. There are many standard algorithms that will call this operator internally.

Comment: Is there a name for the whole `operator()()` by the way?

Comment: @J.Doe I'm not aware of a name for the operator, but sometimes a class which implements this method is called a "functor" because it operates like a function.

Answer (score 32):

You can overload the `()` operator to call your object as if it was a function:

```
class A {
public:
    void operator()(int x, int y) {
        // Do something
    }
};

A x;
x(5, 3); // at this point operator () gets called
```

So the first parentheses are always empty: this is the name of the function: `operator()`, the second parentheses might have parameters (as in my example), but they don't have to (as in your example).

So to call this operator in your particular case you would do something like `task()`.

Comment: operator()() is only called without any parameters? Is there any other cases to run it?

Comment: @forester2012, you get to choose how many parameters there are by declaring the parameters within the second `()` as shown here. You may also declare different `operator()` functions with different parameter lists and C++ will choose the correct one based on the parameters you use when calling it.

Comment: Oh, I mean that if there are other implicit calls except this explicit call task()? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

The first part `operator()` is the way to declare the function that is called when an instance of the class is invoked as a function.  The second pair of parentheses would contain the actual arguments.

With a return value and arguments  this might make a bit more sense:

```
class Adder{
public:
int operator()(int a, int b){
    //operator() -- this is the "name" of the operator
    //         in this case, it takes two integer arguments.
    return a+b;
}
};
Adder a;
assert( 5==a(2,3) );
```

In this context, the `std::thread` will internally invoke `f()` inside the thread, i.e. whatever is inside the body of `operator()` is what gets done inside that thread.

Answer (score 1):

All the hints that were contributed above are correct to sequential programs, I mean, programs without threads. Using threads things change. 
First of all, by default parameters to std::thread are functions and functions parameters. Probably you were studying the book "C++ concurrency in action", and the author shows an interesting example:

```
void do_some_work(); 
thread my_thread(do_some_work); //thread receives the function address
```

Suppose this function:

void do_other_job(int k);
In the body of the code, you should do:

```
k=3; 
thread my_thread2(do_other_job, k);
```

in order to spawn another thread.

So, using threads the compiler interprets f ( in **std::thread my_thread(f);**) by default as a function instead of a class. To change that you have to initiate an operator() to warn the compiler you are working with a class. 
An alternative code could be:

```
class background_task{
public: 
background_task(){
 do_sth(); 
 do_sth_else(); 
 }
void operator()(){} 
}; 
background_task f; 
thread mythread10(f);
```

Eventually, it's not correct, using threads, feeding the operator, so this code doesn't work:

```
void operator()(int x){
do_sth(); 
cout<<"x = "<<x<<endl;
}
```

It happens because all the code inside the brackets are read-only, and cannot be changed during the run-time. If you aim to insert a variable in the constructor, it must be put in the thread initialization. So:

```
class backg{
public: 
backg(int i){
   do_sth(i); 
   }
void operator()(){}
}; 
int main(){
thread mythread{ backg(12) }; //using c++11
return 0; 
}
```

Will run without mistakes, and will perform the function do_sth(12) in the thread spawned.

I hope I have helped.