# Is there a void operator() () for C?

Tags: c, multithreading

I was just looking as some thread code in C++ when I came upon the void operator () () function. I checked StackOverflow [Functionality of void operator()()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857150/functionality-of-void-operator)    and this pretty much explains it. I am wondering if I could that in C for pthread_create().Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

No, C does not feature operator overloading.

The example you linked to is about C++ threads, not pthreads.

In C the same task is done with function pointers:

```
void* run_func(void *ptr)
{
}

...
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run_func, NULL);
```